# Why we cannot add a new property to an object constructor the same way we add a new property to an existing object?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype

I have a function in javascript.

```
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
    this.name = function() {return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;};
}
```

Why we can't add a property to the constructor in javascript like this?

```
Person.hairColor = "black";
```

We can add a property to object easily like this.

```
myPerson = new Person("firstName","lastName",23,"brown");
myPerson.hairColor = "black";
```

Why the first one is not possible, why javascript restricts to add a property to  constructor?

Comment: You *can*, it just won't be inherited by an instance, it'll be a static property

Comment: `Why the first one is not possible` ... how do you know that?

Comment: @JonasWilms When I try to print `myPerson` object after adding `hairColor` it doesn't show newly added property.

Comment: An object constructor is a function. To make it add a new property to the instances that it will create when called, you would need to modify the function behaviour, i.e. rewrite its body. Adding a property to the function object doesn't achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign a property to `Person.hairColor`, that can only be accessed via `Person.hairColor`, and it won't be inherited to instances, as instances inherit from `Person.prototype`. So if you add a property to that, e.g. `Person.prototype.hairColor`, then that will be inherited and can be accessed via the instances (`myPerson.hairColor`).

Note that setting `myPerson.hairColor` won't change the value in the prototype, but will create a new property on the instance, e.g.:

```
  myPerson.hairColor += " and brown";
  console.log(
     Person.prototype.hairColor, // "black"
     myPerson.hairColor, // "black and brown"
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prototype` to add. Example:

```
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
    this.name = function() {return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName};
}

Person.prototype.hairColor = "black";

myPerson = new Person("firstName","lastName",23,"brown");
console.log(myPerson.hairColor); // black
```

Comment: Thanks. But I wanted the reason behind why we can't add it.